# I am trying to fetch data from Firestore database in my ios Swift Project

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to fetch data from team of subscription collection.

[image]

I am trying following code:

```
db.collection("subscriptions").addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
    guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
        print("Error retreiving snapshots \(error!)")
        return
    }

    //print("Current data: \(snapshot.documents.map { $0.data() })")

    for document in snapshot.documents{
        print(document.data())
    }
}
```

Output of my Code

[image]

So, as far concern i am able to fetch the data of collections but not able to get data from team , help me out , Thanx for support

Comment: Can't you just get `document.data()["team"] as? [String: Any]` to get the team info?

Comment: FYI Use  `getDocuments` function instead of `addSnapshotListener`.

Comment: thank you for your support and reply, now want only office id from team , this is the output.                                                    Optional(["developer@ratufa.com": {
    name = "Developer Ratufa";
    officeId = myuPlTBO8sEM4SOQ8rWY;
}, "judd.flamm@whitecoatlabs.io": {
    officeId = myuPlTBO8sEM4SOQ8rWY;
}])

Comment: @Pankaj99 This is a dictionary and you can get it. What is the issue?

Comment: @TheTiger Sir i want to get office id and name , as I am new to firestore and also fresher in ios . this is a normal app in which i have to fetch some data for login verification for those only whose data are present in firestore(mean only those can login whose data are present in database) and after login the data should be visible in table view.

Comment: I mean you already got the data from Firebase so its nothing pending on firebase side. Now you have dictionary so try to parse it there doesn't seem any issue. Are you facing any problem in parsing the data?

Comment: @TheTiger Yes sir, don't know what to do next

Comment: @Pankaj99 What does `document.data()["team"]` print?

Comment: @TheTiger this code is giving following output...                                          Optional(["developer@ratufa.com": {
    name = "Developer Ratufa";
    officeId = myuPlTBO8sEM4SOQ8rWY;
}, "judd.flamm@whitecoatlabs.io": {
    officeId = myuPlTBO8sEM4SOQ8rWY;
}])

Comment: @Pankaj99 I have answered please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to listen every event use `getDocuments` method instead of `addSnapshotListener`.

```
/// This will give you team data
document.data()["team"]
```

After getting the `team` information from firestore. Here is how to get `name` and `officeId`:

```
if let teamInfo = document.data()["team"] as? [String: Any] {
   let teams = teamInfo.map {$0.value}
   for team in teams {
       guard let validTeam = team as? Dictionary<String, Any> else {continue}
       let name = validTeam["name"] as? String ?? ""
       let officeId = validTeam["officeId"] as? String ?? ""
       print("name: \(name), officeId: \(officeId)")
   }
}
```

**Output**

```
name: Developer Ratufa, officeId: myuPlTBO8sEM4SOQ8rWY
name: , officeId: myuPlTBO8sEM4SOQ8rWY
```