# Trying to fetch data matching user thats currently logging in with Swift in Xcode IOS

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using the code below to fetch the 'role' linked to the current uid. Unfortunately I only receive every single piece of data underneath every single uid instead of only the active uid.

I think I have to use something like getdocuments.data or so but I can't seem to get it to work.

Please be very clear when you suggest a piece of code to change because I'm a complete newbie trying to make something.

Below the code is my firestore formatting.

**This is the result of shown code in text format instead of screenshot:**

> User ID post guard: 5izU0b1gl1T7BEwEd43nZtt7eXo1
>
> ["doc1werkgeversverklaring": photo, "doc2salarisstrook": photo, "role": client, "uid": qNbQOvwkoQUC8AvQEUOpXjSxkVn2, "lastname": lastname, "firstname": testUser, "doc3paspoort": photo]
> ["firstname": Jan, "uid": JxfmDN1REebD6WOaV0bHsoXTlZC3, "lastname": Korte]
> ["role": client, "firstname": firstname1, "uid": K0W6chKQRBejYnDmp7KGEgjHOix2, "lastname": lastname1]
> ["firstname": Henry, "uid": 33d5PKLqsyL9OnXGT0CO2vc0art1, "lastname": De Boer]
> ["role": agent, "firstname": Raymond, "uid": gP2sUjEGdVbkVKVxjoGQI1mHzf43, "lastname": Timmers]
> ["role": client, "firstname": firstname2, "uid": S8OjRel3LzScCc2KxxJucEmQZsX2, "lastname": lastname2]
> ["role": agent, "firstname": Stephan, "uid": 5izU0b1gl1T7BEwEd43nZtt7eXo1, "lastname": Timmers]**

Screenshot of code and result:
[image: Screenshot of code and result]

Screenshot of Firestore lay-out:
[image: Screenshot of Firestore lay-out]

```swift
//Prints current user uid
guard let uid12 = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
      return
  }

  print("User ID post guard: \(uid12)")


//Check if the role attached to the uid12 is "Agent" or "Client"
let db = Firestore.firestore()

db.collection("users").addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
    guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
        print("Error retreiving snapshots \(error!)")
        return
    }

    for document in snapshot.documents{
        print(document.data())
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the logging output as text instead of a screenshot? I'd also really like to see the output of this line in there: `print("User ID post guard: \(uid12)")`.

Comment: Hi Frank, the outcome of that line is visible in the imgur link with the screenshot I replied in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're attaching a listener to the entire `users` collection, so that indeed loads all user documents and prints them.

To [observe a single document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-local-changes) you'd do something like:

```
db.collection("users").document(uid12).addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, error in
    guard let document = documentSnapshot else {
        print("Error fetching document: \(error!)")
        return
    }

    print(document.data())
    print(document.data()["role"])
}
```

Comment: Hi there I used your line of code and the following happened:  

https://imgur.com/a/76qU9pu

Comment: By the way, would be nice to get only the documents info from that one uid but im actually looking for only the value of "role" within this uid, as shown in the Firestore screenshot.

Comment: My problem seems to be similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50525462/i-am-trying-to-fetch-data-from-firestore-database-in-my-ios-swift-project but in his question he's looking for "teams" while i'm looking for "role" and I cant seem to get the given solution to work for me.

Comment: In the screenshot it looks like there is no signed in user, which means that you can't load data for a specific user. I updated my answer to also show how to print a specific field.

Comment: What I want to do here is: 
A user thats trying to sign in with the field "role": client, should be send to ClientPanelViewCollector. All others (only being the agents then) should be send to AgentPanelViewCollector. So when someone is logging in I want to see if they are an agent or a client. I dont actually care how we get that information as long as we are. I have tried your code and unfortunately it gets me the: "Nil" response. Probably because i'm approaching this situation wrongly, hence my explanation. Could you still help me somehow? Even willing to share sourcecode through github.